# Which data structure should be used in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, computer-science

Assuming that there are three variables, "staffId", "subject" and "sessionTime"

and the examples are:

```
<9600001, info2001, Tue3>,
<9600001, info2002, Wed4>,
<9600002, info2001, Wed2>,
<9600001, info2001, Thu9>,
<9600001, info2003, Fri10>,
<9600002, info2004, Wed4>
```

Finally the output should be:

```
STAFF_ID HOURS
 9600002 4
 9600001 7
```

Calculation: Observe that staff 9600001 has 4 actual sessions, and is involved in 3 different subjects, so this
makes 4+3=7 hours in total.

To code this question, I decided to use nested HashMap, like

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> submission = new HashMap<Integer, TreeMap<String, String>>();
```

but the problem was that, the tree-map replaces its previous value as the value has to be unique. For example, when I put

<9600001, info2001, Tue3> and <9600001, info2001, Thu9> into the map,

in the hash-map, there should be

9600001, info2001 - Tue3 and Thu9

but the previous value is replaced so there is only one value existing:

9600001, info2001 - Thu9

Can someone please tell me how to approach to this question?

Which data structures should I use?

Comment: `Map<StaffIdType, List<SomeStruct>>`, where `SomeStruct` has fields for subject and session time.

Comment: Why does a different subject add another hour to the total time? Staff 1 has 4 one hour sessions and staff 2 has 2. Why would the different subjects add more hours to the total?

Answer (score 3):

Use `List` of records.

```
class Record {
  int staffId;
  String subject;
  String sessionTime;
}

List<Record> submissions = new ArrayList<>();
```

or `Map` of `List`

```
class Record {
  String subject;
  String sessionTime;
}

Map<Integer, List<Record>> submissions = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: first option is preferable. Java is after all a class/object based language. keep it simple :)

Comment: I'm not sure about it being preferable in terms of performance. To get all the records for staffId `X` in the first option, you'd have to loop over the entire list. Whereas in the second option, you can get them by key.

Comment: `new Map<>()` is incorrect. It should be a `Map` implementation like `new HashMap<>()`;

Comment: @Synch right, I replaced Map with HashMap, and List with ArrayList. Performance - if you calculate this one time then List version is faster, as map building also isn't free. So my answer to question "which is better" is "it depends" :)

Comment: Yes, of course it depends. My point was to @JackFlamp's comment saying the first option is preferable as if it was set in stone. The general rule in List vs Map is if your list is small, List wins, otherwise Map wins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom object and a `Map` for this problem.

```
Map<Integer, CustomObject> map = new HashMap<Integer, CustomObject>();
```

and

```
class CustomObject {
    int staffIdCount; //Number of distinct staffId records (e.g. for 9600001 value will be 4)
    Set<String> subject = new HashSet<String>(); //distinct subjects
}
```

Functionality will be like below:

when you encounter `9600001` perform below operation

```
    if(map.containsKey(9600001))
    {
        CustomObject tmp = map.get(9600001);
        tmp.staffIdCount+=1;
        tmp.subject.add("info2001"); //the corresponding subject
        map.put(9600001, tmp);
    }
    else
    {
        CustomObject tmp = new CustomObject();
        tmp.staffIdCount +=1;
        tmp.subject.add("info2001");

        map.put(9600001, tmp);
    }
```

***EDIT:***  so `staffIdCount` will give you number of `staffId`s and size of `subject` will give you distinct count of `subject`

Answer (score 0):

Java is an object oriented language so you are best off making classes to represent the items you want to record and manipulate. In your case there are staff, subjects and sessions:

```
class Staff {
    private final String id;
}

class Subject {
    private final String id;
}

class Session {
    private final Staff staff;
    private final Subject subject;
    int period;
}
```

If you have a list of sessions then you can fairly easily generate a map from staff to sum of period (for example):

```
List<Session> sessions;

Map<Staff, Integer> staffTotalTime = sessions.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Session::getStaff, summingInt(Session::getPeriod));
```

My recommendation is to not start by modelling data to optimise access. Form data structures that are a simple and elegant representation of the relationships between the objects and then manipulate it into other forms when required. It would be trivial to change the statement above to sum by subject or create an average or just about anything else without having to change the data model you use to store the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Though the counting formula is a bit strange (count distinct subject + count sessionTime), I guess what you meant was `Map<Integer, Map<String, List<String>>>`. I've come up with 2 methods, please modify if necessary.

```
public class Dummy {

    public Map<Integer, Integer> countHours(List<Submission> submissions) {

        Map<Integer, Integer> res = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Set<String>> subjectMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, List<String>> sessionTimeMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Submission s : submissions) {
            subjectMap.computeIfAbsent(s.getStaffId(), v -> new HashSet<>()).add(s.getSubject());
            sessionTimeMap.computeIfAbsent(s.getStaffId(), v -> new ArrayList<>()).add(s.getSessionTime());
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<String>> e : subjectMap.entrySet()) {
            res.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().size());
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> e : sessionTimeMap.entrySet()) {
            res.merge(e.getKey(), e.getValue().size(), Integer::sum);
        }

        return res;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Integer> countHours2(List<Submission> submissions) {

        Map<Integer, Map<String, Long>> collect = submissions.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Submission::getStaffId,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Submission::getSubject, Collectors.counting())));

        return collect.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        e -> e.getValue().size() +
                                e.getValue().values().stream().mapToInt(Number::intValue).sum()));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

        List<Submission> submissions = new ArrayList<>();
        submissions.add(new Submission(9600001, "info2001", "Tue3"));
        submissions.add(new Submission(9600001, "info2002", "Wed4"));
        submissions.add(new Submission(9600002, "info2001", "Wed2"));
        submissions.add(new Submission(9600001, "info2001", "Thu9"));
        submissions.add(new Submission(9600001, "info2003", "Fri10"));
        submissions.add(new Submission(9600002, "info2004", "Wed4"));

        System.out.println(countHours(submissions)); // {9600002=4, 9600001=7}

        System.out.println(countHours2(submissions)); // {9600002=4, 9600001=7}
    }

}

// In case you have lombok
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Submission {

    private int staffId;
    private String subject;
    private String sessionTime;

    // In case you do not have lombok

//    Submission(int staffId, String subject, String sessionTime) {
//        this.staffId = staffId;
//        this.subject = subject;
//        this.sessionTime = sessionTime;
//    }
//
//    public int getStaffId() {
//        return staffId;
//    }
//
//    public void setStaffId(int staffId) {
//        this.staffId = staffId;
//    }
//
//    public String getSubject() {
//        return subject;
//    }
//
//    public void setSubject(String subject) {
//        this.subject = subject;
//    }
//
//    public String getSessionTime() {
//        return sessionTime;
//    }
//
//    public void setSessionTime(String sessionTime) {
//        this.sessionTime = sessionTime;
//    }

}
```